# If value is equal with a key in the given dictionary, how can I append to the key of the said value the value of the first key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

First of all, I am sorry for the confusing title but let's assume we have a dictionary:

```
dict = {'Parent': 'Grandparent', 'Daughter': 'Parent', 'Son': 'Parent'}
```

How do I reach this output?

```
new_dict = {'Parent': 'Grandparent', 'Daughter': ['Parent', 'Grandparent'], 'Son': ['Parent', 'Grandparent']}
```

I was thinking of this:

```
for key in dict:
     for value in dict.values():
       if key == value: #I didn't use 'in' because the string 'Parent' is part of 'Grandparent
         #some action
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution seems quite Pythonic to me:

```
dict_ = {'Parent': 'Grandparent', 'Daughter': 'Parent', 'Son': 'Parent'}

new_dict = {
    k: list(set(v for v in dict_.values()
    if v != k)) for k,v in dict_.items()
}
```

Please, note: do not give your dictionary `dict` name as this is a keyword so you can get into troubles.

Comment: It works perfectly on the example I gave. While my dictionary is a little bit more complicated and it doesn't work on it, thank you for the solution. I'll come back if I need help again.

Comment: @SebastianManea If it solves the problem of the question you asked, please mark the answer as accepted. If you have another question about different conditions, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

This solution also works for your case.

```
sample_dict = {'Parent': 'Grandparent', 'Daughter': 'Parent', 'Son': 'Parent'}

for key,value in sample_dict.items():
    if value in sample_dict:
        sample_dict[key]=[value,sample_dict[value]]

print(sample_dict)
{'Parent': 'Grandparent', 'Daughter': ['Parent', 'Grandparent'], 'Son': ['Parent','Grandparent']}
```

Comment: This solution works even if in the dictionary there are more unrelated key, value pairs. Excellent! Thank you

Comment: @SebastianManea Thanks for the Comment.Upvote the answer if you can.

Comment: I upvoted but votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @SebastianManea Thanks.I suggest reading python basics will help you a lot.